# Overleaf: automatic backup to Github?

Tags: overleaf, git

I have installed Overleaf in the free version on my server. Everything works fine. Is it anyhow possible to connect Overleaf with my Github and hence store my paper there as well? Just in case my server has some errors, so I do not lose it if problems should occur?

Comment: I don't think so. This functionality is only available with a paid subscription to Overleaf. https://www.overleaf.com/learn/how-to/Using_Git_and_GitHub (Although maybe I'm misunderstanding your question if you have a local version of Overleaf).

Comment: (I'm on support staff at Overleaf.) As Alan said, this is not possible. The GitHub integration (along with other third-party syncing integrations) is only available on overleaf.com, not self-hosted instances. For further details about the differences between cloud-hosted and self-hosted, see our [features table](https://www.overleaf.com/for/enterprises/features).

Comment: Couldn't you just run a cron job or similar on the server to do a git push?